# unifornly convergent sequence of function

Tags: calculus

another question about the same function (didnt want to ask 2 questions at the same time)

we have the next sequence of function:
$$ \forall x \ge 0, f_{n}(x)=\frac{nx} {e^x+n+x} $$

True or false - $$f_{n} (x) $$ uniformly converge for $$ x\ge 0$$

in my opinion its false.

Answer (score 1):

**This is false.**

$(f_n)$ doesn't converges uniformly. If it was the case, it would converges towards its pointwise limit which is the function $f(x)=x$. Hence $$g_n(x)= f_n(x)-f(x)=- \frac{xe^x+x^2}{e^x+n+x}$$ would converges uniformly to $0$. However, this is not the case as you can see considering $(g_n(n))$.

However $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $0$ on all compact interval because $$\vert g_n(x) \vert= \left\vert \frac{xe^x+x^2}{e^x+n+x}\right\vert \le \frac{xe^x+x^2}{n} \le \frac{ae^a+a^2}{n}$$ for $0 \le x \le a$.

Comment: You have edited the wrong answer. The compact convergence is pertinent for the other question.

Comment: After the definition of $g_n(x)$, why not continue like this? If $g_n$ converged uniformly to zero, then $\sup_{x \geq 0}\left|g_n(x)\right| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. However, $\sup_{x \geq 0} \left|g_n(x)\right| \geq \left|g_n(n)\right| = \frac{ne^n + n^2}{e^n + 2n} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, which is a contradiction.